# Shade colors (change 'brightness') based on discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2

It would be nice to use color shading to indicate levels of a discrete value for example.

So instead of this:

```
ggplot( mpg ) + 
    geom_boxplot( 
        aes(x=manufacturer,y=hwy,fill=interaction(str_match(trans,"auto|manual")[,1],manufacturer)) 
    )
```

I would want to have a specific color per manufacturer, and then have it slightly darker for either of "manual" or "auto". Except I wouldn't want to specify every single color and its darker shade for the levels of my values, I'm happy to go with the current color palette.

There are multiple relatively straightforward to adjust brightness of a color, I'm interested in wiring this into ggplot at the moment.

Are there for example hooks available that I could tap into, to use something like a *shade* aesthetics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although changing the alpha is great, it is not exactly changing the "brightness", but the transparency of the graphs.

Here a possible workaround, also using alpha, but for an overlying black box plot with the same groups.

I added the color aesthetic to the first plot in order to separate the groups by `trans`.

You can then play around to get the right 'brightness values' by changing the alpha in `scale_alpha_manual`

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg) +
# the ugly interaction call is to avoid weirdly coloured outlier dots. 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = hwy, fill = manufacturer, 
                   group = interaction(manufacturer,(str_match(trans,"auto|manual"))))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = hwy, alpha = str_match(trans,"auto|manual")), fill = 'black') +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.1,0.4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it (without editing the data frame), using `alpha` to get your "brightness":

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)


ggplot( mpg ) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=manufacturer,y=hwy,fill=interaction(str_match(trans,"auto|manual")[,1],manufacturer), col = manufacturer,
                   alpha = ifelse(grepl("auto", trans), .5, .8))) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

The colors can be modified using something like "+ scale_col_manual()".

Comment: You never need to test `. == TRUE`, it *already* either is true or false. In [some cases](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html), it's best to use [`isTRUE`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html). Upvote, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `alpha` on `aes` function.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_alpha.html

```
mpg_data <- mpg %>%
mutate(trans = gsub('\\(.*$', '', trans))

ggplot( mpg_data ) + 
geom_boxplot( 
aes(x=manufacturer,y=hwy,fill=manufacturer, alpha = trans))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `alpha` from `aes`, you can just apply the function you already used in the original post to control the transparency of the bars, while assigning `manufacturer` to `fill` to control the color of the bars.

```r
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg,
       aes(x = manufacturer,
           y = hwy,
           fill = manufacturer,
           alpha = str_match(trans, "auto|manual")[,1])) +
geom_boxplot()
```