# Conditionally color barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, colorbar

I would like to conditionally color these mirrors barplots.

I want to colour according to the disease and the hospital. I want the diseases that have the first two identical characters to have the same colour (i.e. D4001 and D4002 will have the same colour; D3000, D3001 and D3003 will have the same colour).

I also want to stratify the color on the hospital so that the transparency or contrast of the barplot will be different from one hospital to another for the same disease (for example a disease D4 in hospital A will be red and a disease D4 in hospital B will be transparent red).

```
set.seed(0)
ID=1:20
Hospital<-sample(c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)))
Disease<-c("D1000",rep("D2001",2),rep("D2000",3),rep("D3000",4),
rep("D3001",2),rep("D3003",4),rep("D4001",3),"D4002")

data$Disease<-as.factor(data$Disease)
data<-data.frame(ID,Hospital,Disease)
datacount<-data%>%group_by(Hospital,Disease)%>%count
datacount$n2<-ifelse(datacount$Hospital=="B",datacount$n,-datacount$n)

ggplot(datacount,aes(x=Disease,y=n2))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=Hospital))+coord_flip()
```

All I know how to do is either color by hospital or by disease individually.

[image] [image]

Comment: For example when you look at disease D4001 in diagram 2. There is nothing to disaggregate the part attributable to hospital A and the part attributable to hospital B because everything is purple. I want to keep the same colour for this disease but just change the contrast e.g. light purple for hospital A and dark purple for hospital B. I want to do the same for each disease group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an alpha to define the hospital. ([very similar thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747652/shade-colors-change-brightness-based-on-discrete-values/59779099#59779099)). Credit to using substring for the disease goes to [user Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e)

```r
ggplot(datacount,aes(x=Disease, y=n2)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=substr(Disease, 1,2))) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Disease") +
    geom_col(aes(alpha=Hospital), fill = "grey") + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.1,0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: it' s just great. Thank you so much.